# Finding the null in a method invocation chain

Tags: java, exception, null

I am looking for a quick way of figuring out what part of a [chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) is null.

An **example** to illustrate the point:

```
public class Chain {
    private Chain chain;

    public Chain returnChain() {
        return chain;
    }

    public void addChain(Chain chain) {
        this.chain=chain;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Hello!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chain c1 = new Chain();
        c1.addChain(new Chain());

        System.out.println(c1.returnChain().returnChain().returnChain().returnChain());
    }
}
```

This will obviously throw a `NullPointerException`. (I know how to alter the code to make it obvious what part of the chain threw the `NullPointerException`, but I would like some way of figuring it out with existing code.)

Comment: What do you want as output? Hashcode of chain containing null?

Comment: I want something like "c1.returnChain().returnChain() returned null".

Comment: @ChristianJonassen: Are you looking for a solution for this particular piece of code or for something more generic where you're making a sequence of calls to arbitrary functions?

Comment: Can I assume that using a debugger is out of the question? Because that would be the simplest option. Run the code with remote debugging, set an "exception thrown" breakpoint, then inspect the variables on that line to see which is returning a null.

Comment: @Erica: Sure, but I am looking for a way of getting a better exception message when it happens in the first place.

Comment: @christian-neverdal Maybe this JEP https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8220715 helps by providing details like e.g. "Cannot write field 'nullInstanceField' because 'this.nullInstanceField' is null."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stack trace for a typical NPE, you're given the line number it occurred on. So assuming `System.out.println(c1.returnChain().returnChain().returnChain().returnChain());` is on line 144 (just picked that randomly) your NPE stack trace should look something like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at your.package.Chain(Chain.java:144)
```

So, if you put your chain call on multiple lines, it should show you where the exception is.

I wrote up this little example:

```
package bla;

public class Something {
    public static int count = 0;
    public Something get() {
        if(count == 2) {
            return null;
        }
        ++count;
        return new Something();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Something something = new Something();
        Something test = something.get()
                                .get()
                                    .get()
                                        .get() // Should throw NPE
                                            .get()
                                                .get();
    }
}
```

And it gave me the NPE says:  at bla.Something.main(Something.java:18) - exactly where the NPE occurred in the chain.

Screen shot...

[image: Showing what this would look like...]

Comment: I tried the same but it didn't worked for me! I logged the 1st line of the istruction where the NPE is thrown

Comment: Does someone care to explain the downvote?  I don't mind it if I'm wrong about something but I'd like an explanation at least.

Comment: @thermz, could you post the code from when you tried this and it didn't work?

Comment: I tried a my piece of code which is quite similar to yours and it didn't worked, so i tried exactly your code (copy and paste) and the result is always the first line of the Java instuction, in your code is the line of `Something test = something.get()`... I also tried to launch it as Java5, Java6 and nothing changed. BTW I've never seen a stacktrace where the line number is not the first line of an instruction. Anyone feels free to correct me if I'm wrong, my JVM says I'm right

Comment: That answer is not wrong, with the correct compiler settings (I pasted it Eclipse and it run as it should with no code change). Normally you would try to keep the number of chained method calls to a minimum. Simply creating some `final` variables on the stack does not change the performance much, and would certainly return the line number when an exception is thrown *unless your compiler settings do not include line numbers in the class* .

Comment: @owlstead I'm sorry, can you expand a bit? Which compiler settings I have to change in order to print the line of the NPE (which you are telling me is NOT the 1st line of the instruction) and how can I do to change those settings? I really don't understand what are you talking about when you say "creating some final variables on the stack {...}  and would certainly return the line number when an exception is thrown"

Comment: See screen shot, this it eclipse helios fresh out of the box w/java 6.

Comment: Ok, I see you were right, but please someone tell me why I still getting this: http://mrrmsolver.appspot.com/npe.png

Comment: Since seems that your answer "can" works I removed the downvote, but I'll not upvote it until someone explain me why the hell my compiler does not like it

Comment: It's a terrible piece of code regarding the use of count++, which is defined as a static variable, but is updated through non-static method calls. I haven't got FindBugs installed at my home computer, but I'm pretty sure it would complain. Could be a debugger bug or a difference during running of the application e.g. because of optimalization.

Comment: @owlstead thank you for your answer but I'm still not able to get why it doesn't work for me! And that make me so sad... it could be a revolutionary discover for my java programming style :'(

Comment: My guess would be "keep unused local variables", but it could be reordering of instructions as well. Hard to tell, and I don't know your compiler/runtime environment.

Comment: It would make an evolutionary change if you just introduced a few local variables and refactored your code so less chaining is necessary and null's cannot be returned. A revolutionary change would be if Java would only return null if a variable would be made (e.g.) "nullable". But maybe that's for the next language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7219/discussion-between-thermz-and-owlstead)

Answer (score 2):

For the particular piece of code that you have, try adding the following method to your `Chain` class:

```
    public static Chain checkChainSequence(Chain first, int count) {
        Chain thisChain = first;
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("firstChain");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Chain nextChain = thisChain.returnChain();
            out.append(".returnChain()");
            if (nextChain == null) {
                out.append(" returned null");
                System.out.println(out);
                return null;
            }
            thisChain = nextChain;
        }
        return thisChain;
    }
```

You can use it as follows:

```
    Chain c1 = new Chain();
    c1.addChain(new Chain());

    // To check c1.returnChain().returnChain().returnChain():
    Chain.checkChainSequence(c1, 3);
```

This would print:

```
    firstChain.returnChain().returnChain() returned null
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not getting it, but what about just `returnChain() == null` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to `Chain` class variable like `position` for determing position of element in chain:

```
public class Chain {
    private Chain chain;
    private int position;

    public Chain returnChain() {
        if (chain == null) {
            System.out.println(position + " chain is null");
        } else {
            chain.position = position + 1;
        }
        return chain;
    }

    public void addChain(Chain chain) {
        this.chain=chain;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Hello!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chain c1 = new Chain();
        c1.addChain(new Chain());
        c1.position = 0;
        System.out.println(c1.returnChain().returnChain().returnChain().returnChain());
    }
}
```

Of course it's not thread safe and looks weird. But is should write position of null.
Simpler version:

```
public int findPositionOfNullChain(Chain chain) {
     int position = 0;
     while (chain != null) {
         chain = chain.returnChain();
         position++;
     }
     return position;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that Christian Jonassen need a solution for this particular piece of code (which is clearly an example), I think he is looking for a solution to always find a NPE in a "chained" call of methods.. something like `this.getTown().getAvenue().getNumber().getFloor()` if avenue is null there is no good solution to find always where NPE is thrown.. unless you don't want to try & catch each call...

Comment: For that scenario you can use `npe.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()`. Doesn't help here, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately no, in this situation (the owner of the question's code) calling `npe.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()` will return "main"

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the Chain class, you can do this to find out which part is null:

```
Chain c1 = new Chain();
c1.addChain(new Chain());
Chain preNullChain = c1;
Chain returnedChained = null;

while ((returnedChained = preNullChain.returnChain()) != null) {
    preNullChain = returnedChained;
}
//here, preNullChain is the last Chain that is not null
```

Or you can just catch the null pointer exception to print null

```
Chain returnedChain = null;
Chain c1 = new Chain();
c1.addChain(new Chain());
try {
returnedChain = c1.returnChain().returnChain().returnChain().returnChain();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
}
System.out.println(returnedChain); //now here will print null as what you asked for
```